# Bug in markdown rendering engine

Tags: bug, markdown

If I want to mark as *italic* a paragraph within an unordered list then I can do so only once. Any subsequent paragraphs marked the same way show visible asterisks instead

For example, I wanted the fourth bullet point of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34663787/622310) to have the first paragraph in roman type and the second and third in italic. I marked the second as italic successfully, but I could find no way of also italicising the third

Comment: Instead of asterisks, try underscores to see if that works. (As a workaround.)

Comment: You have `*larger*` in your third part so remove the asterisks and then move them around the entire part, then everything is italic *(Pro-tip: Use an IDE for writing text :)*

Comment: @Rizier123: Can you suggest a WIndows IDE for writing markdown?

Comment: @Borodin It was just meant to be a joke ;) Since many times on SO when dealing with syntax errors an IDE helps the most. (I don't think there is an IDE for markdown)

Comment: @Rizier123: Ah, sorry! It seems like a useful thing to have though as the site itself is far from ideal

Comment: Actually it even seems that there exists an editor for it (after a quick google search): http://markdownpad.com/

Comment: @Rizier123: I'll take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I could](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34663787/revisions). Just escape the * around "larger" with a backslash \.

---

> - Since the paths to the files to be archived are stored in an array anyway there no reason not to use the `create_archive` class method to build and save your files all in one go
>
>   *The second parameter to `create_archive` is a compression method. I have set it to zero to request no compression and maximum speed, but you can enable gzip or bzip compression by passing `COMPRESS_GZIP` or `COMPRESS_BZIP`*
>
>   *Although the module's documentation discourages it, you can also set this parameter to 1 through 9 to indicate a level of gzip compression. If you are archiving text files then I highly recommend that you use 1 or 2 here. Passing `COMPRESS_GZIP` results in a gzip compression level of 9, which is by far the slowest and can often result in a *larger* file than lower compressions. A value of 1 will often give you a file one third of the size of the uncompressed archive, while 2 may give you another five percent reduction. After that there is usually very little gain*

---

Or, if you want more emphasis, just **bold** it.

> - Since the paths to the files to be archived are stored in an array anyway there no reason not to use the `create_archive` class method to build and save your files all in one go
>
>   *The second parameter to `create_archive` is a compression method. I have set it to zero to request no compression and maximum speed, but you can enable gzip or bzip compression by passing `COMPRESS_GZIP` or `COMPRESS_BZIP`*
>
>   *Although the module's documentation discourages it, you can also set this parameter to 1 through 9 to indicate a level of gzip compression. If you are archiving text files then I highly recommend that you use 1 or 2 here. Passing `COMPRESS_GZIP` results in a gzip compression level of 9, which is by far the slowest and can often result in a **larger** file than lower compressions. A value of 1 will often give you a file one third of the size of the uncompressed archive, while 2 may give you another five percent reduction. After that there is usually very little gain*

---

You could remove the italics if instead of `a *larger* file` you used `a* larger *file`:

> - Since the paths to the files to be archived are stored in an array anyway there no reason not to use the `create_archive` class method to build and save your files all in one go
>
>   *The second parameter to `create_archive` is a compression method. I have set it to zero to request no compression and maximum speed, but you can enable gzip or bzip compression by passing `COMPRESS_GZIP` or `COMPRESS_BZIP`*
>
>   *Although the module's documentation discourages it, you can also set this parameter to 1 through 9 to indicate a level of gzip compression. If you are archiving text files then I highly recommend that you use 1 or 2 here. Passing `COMPRESS_GZIP` results in a gzip compression level of 9, which is by far the slowest and can often result in a* larger *file than lower compressions. A value of 1 will often give you a file one third of the size of the uncompressed archive, while 2 may give you another five percent reduction. After that there is usually very little gain*