# How do I include literal asterisks in italicized text?

Tags: support, markdown

Is there any way I could make the following sentence be formatted italic?

*.h or *.hpp for your class definitions

I tryed so far:

"**.h or *.hpp for your class definitions*"

**.h or *.hpp for your class definitions*

"* *.h or *.hpp for your class definitions*"

- *.h or *.hpp for your class definitions*

But as you can see every output isn't quite what is planed.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314204/2675154

Comment: Use underscore to start and stop the italics: _*.hpp_ (typed as `_*.hpp_`).  If you need both stars and underscores, then you have to work harder.

Answer (score 13):

Within Markdown, you can use [backslashes](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) as escape characters:

```
*\*.h or \*.hpp for your class definitions*
```

becomes:

**.h or *.hpp for your class definitions*

Alternatively, you can mix in some HTML; using `<i>` would also work:

```
<i>*.h or *.hpp for your class definitions</i>
```

outputs:

**.h or *.hpp for your class definitions*

Comment: The advantage of backslashes is that they also work in comments.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks - I reordered my answer. <i>I didn't know that HTML *wasn't* supported in comments.</i>